How to get VCenter VM or host details of associated datastore using Rest APIs
Using opentelemetry receiver I am getting metrics for datastore. But the metrics holds information about datastore name and Vcenter IP. But doesn't give information about which VM this datastore is associated with. Is there any API available to get VM or Host details associated to this datastore
I am using opentelemetry receiver to get metrics for VM, Host and Datastore. My requirement is I need to get VM details based on datastore name. Any Rest APIs available to use that vcenter are exposing
